# Render javascript after 'create' method completes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm working on creating an ajax form that will execute a few functions after the successful completion of the 'create' method in my rails application. It revolves around looking up a word's definitions, displaying them, then removing them from the screen once the user saves their desired definitions. The problem I'm having is accessing the functions rollUp and revertButtons (stored in words.js) from success.js.erb. I even tried just putting the functions in application.js, but it still doesn't work. Right now, the success.js.erb isn't even executing at all when those functions are included in the file... Any ideas?

create action:

```
if @word.save!
    params['word_definition'].each do |definition|
        if @word.definitions.create(text: definition)
            numDefs += 1
        end
    end
    respond_to do |format|
        if numDefs > 0  
            format.js { render action: "success" }
        end
    end
else
    format.js { render action: "failure" }
end
```

words.js:

```
function submitForm(){
    if(isSubmittable()){
        $('#findWord form').serialize();
        $('#findWord form').submit();
    }
}
// other functions, like revertButtons() and rollUp() are stored here too
```

success.js.erb:

```
revertButtons();
rollUp();
$('<div />', {  class: "alert alert-success",
            text: "The word has been saved",
         }).wrap('<div class="single_error" />').parent().appendTo("#fieldAndErrorsContainer");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I feel like an idiot. I was declaring all of my functions inside of $(document).ready(), so it was relegated to the scope of that function and couldn't be accessed from elsewhere. Lesson learned.